# Job.join() in coroutine is not waiting for task to finish first

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Whenever the last item in the shopping list is added to the shopping cart, I have logic in the `Jetpack Compose` UI that checks this and displays an alert dialog if all items have been added to the cart. I want to wait until the database is updated before checking if all items are in the cart each time an item is added to the cart, but the alert dialog is displayed immediately before the database update operation has a chance to finish first even when using `Job.join()`. What could be wrong with the code?

**Dao**

```
@Update(entity = ShoppingListItemEntity::class)
suspend fun updateShoppingListItem(item: ShoppingListItemEntity): Int
```

**Repository**

```
override suspend fun updateShoppingListItem(shoppingListItem: ShoppingListItem): Int {
    return shoppingListItemDao.updateShoppingListItem(
        shoppingListItemMapper.mapToEntity(shoppingListItem)
    )
}
```

**Use case**

```
class UpdateShoppingListItemUseCase@Inject constructor(
    private val shoppingListItemsRepository: ShoppingListItemsRepository
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(shoppingListItem: ShoppingListItem): Int {
        return shoppingListItemsRepository.updateShoppingListItem(shoppingListItem)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private fun updateShoppingListItemInDb(item: ShoppingListItem) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val job = launch {
            updateShoppingListItemUseCase(item)
        }

        job.join()

        //This line runs immediately
        setStateValue(IS_CHECK_IF_LAST_ITEM_IN_SHOPPING_CART, true) 
    }
}
```

**It executes immediately with async await also:**

```
private fun updateShoppingListItemInDb(item: ShoppingListItem) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val asyncTask = async {
            updateShoppingListItemUseCase(item)
        }

        val rowsAffected = asyncTask.await()

        if(rowsAffected == 1) {
            //This line executes immediately 
            setStateValue(IS_CHECK_IF_LAST_ITEM_IN_SHOPPING_CART, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the inner `launch()` call? Why not just remove it, and have `updateShoppingListItemUseCase(item)` and `setStateValue(IS_CHECK_IF_LAST_ITEM_IN_SHOPPING_CART, true)` in what is now your outer `launch()` lambda?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that already, but the code is not running sequentially. the `setStateValue()` line is called immediately while the database is in the process of updating the shopping list item. This is what I want to prevent.

Comment: "the setStateValue() line is called immediately while the database is in the process of updating the shopping list item" -- then your problem would seem to be in `updateShoppingListItemUseCase()`. "This is what I want to prevent" -- sure, but your solution will not work, because it does not do anything. Launching a coroutine, then `join()`-ing that coroutine immediately afterward, is the same as not launching the coroutine in the first place.

Comment: Do you maybe use `viewModelScope.launch {}` in the `updateShoppingListItemUseCase()` as well? By doing this you have no way to write sequential code. Just don't do this and instead make your functions suspend and don't launch anything in the background.

Comment: @broot I removed a call to `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` in the repository, but it didn't fix the problem. But the repository function calling the `Dao` update query is a suspend function because that `Dao` query is a suspend function as well.

Comment: @broot I updated the question with the `Dao`, `Repository`, and `UseCase` code.

Comment: This code looks good to me. Could you add some logs directly before and after the call to `updateShoppingListItemUseCase()` to make sure it is really executed immediately? Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @broot I placed logs before and after it, and the logs are shown at the same time. There is no pause at all.

Comment: @broot I tried using `async await` instead, and it still executes immediately. I updated the question with this attempted solution.

Comment: Similarly to your initial approach with launch + join, async + await doesn't make too much sense. It is pretty much the same as invoking the function directly. But I have no clues on what is the problem in your case.

Comment: How are you determining that the function from your DAO is returning before the database operation is complete?

Comment: @Tenfour04 If I understand your question correctly, I'm determining that by getting the number-of-rows-affected value with `async.await()` as shown in the updated question above.

Comment: @broot How is it the same? If I don't use `launch + join` or `async + await`, `updateShoppingListItemUseCase(item)` will execute asynchronously, and then `setStateValue(IS_CHECK_IF_LAST_ITEM_IN_SHOPPING_CART, true)` will execute immediately before the the database is updated, causing the dialog to appear when it shouldn't.

Comment: If `updateShoppingListItemUseCase()` is a function from a DAO, it executes synchronously (whether or not it is designated as a `suspend` function). That's how Room is designed. And how could it return the number of rows edited if it didn't work synchronously?

Comment: `updateShoppingListItemUseCase` will probably have to be a suspend function, and you will have to not launch in it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write something like

```
private suspend fun updateShoppingListItemInDb(item: ShoppingListItem) = coroutineScope {
        val asyncTask = async {
            updateShoppingListItemUseCase(item)
        }

        val rowsAffected = asyncTask.await()

        if(rowsAffected == 1) {
            //This line executes immediately 
            setStateValue(IS_CHECK_IF_LAST_ITEM_IN_SHOPPING_CART, true)
        }
}
```

You can just leave it at that; you don't need to reference `viewModelScope` in this function.